# webpack4 copy-webpack-plugin error: Unexpected Character '@'

Tags: javascript, webpack-4

Ive gone through the SO questions and the answered ones seem to only be related to CSS/SASS module rules.

I'm simply trying to copy files (retaining folder structure) from *src* to *public*, no hashing etc so I'm using CopyWebpackPlugin - the same as in Webpack 3

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname,'/public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        // plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
                        // presets: ['es2015','react']
                        // plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ["style-loader","css-loader","sass-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['public']),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        }),

        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {from: 'images', to: 'images' },
            {context: 'images', from: '**/*', to: 'images' },
            {context: 'vendor', from: '**/*', to: 'vendor' },
            {context: 'data', from: '**/*', to: 'data' }
        ]),
    ]
};
```

There are several folders of images are stored inside src/images/**.*
The above CopyWebpackPlugin setup worked fine in Webpack3 but I keep getting this error:

> ERROR in ./src/images/logos/logo-gs_transp-LT.png 1:0 Module parse
>   failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0) You may need an appropriate
>   loader to handle this file type.

Comment: If you remove the CopyWebpackPlugin, does the error still appears?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a loader to handle the image file types. For example:

```
module: {
  rules: [{
   test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|gif|ico)$/,
   loader: 'file-loader',
  }]
}
```